# Hadoop : unable to load native hadoop library

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I know that this is a famous question across internet and there are tons of websites showing how to solve this issue and there are hell lots of QA on SO too. BUT **NONE** of them helped me and I am frustrated now. So I am giving every details I can, if I overlooked anything, I appreciate your help.

```
**OS** : Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit
**Hadoop version** : Hadoop 3.0.0-alpha3
**bashrc** : 

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"

**core-site.xml** : 

<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/hadoopec/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>Temporary Directory.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  <description>Use HDFS as file storage engine</description>
</property>

 **hdfs-env.sh**

export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -XX:-PrintWarnings -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

**hdfs-site.xml**

<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.permission</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop/tmp/hdfs/name</value>
  </property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoopec/hadoop/tmp/hdfs/data</value>
  </property>
```

If anyone needs some more informations, feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by downloading hadoop 2.8.0 and doing all exact configuration as I did with previous hadoop, eventhough I don't know what exactly was causing the error or warning? `localhost:50070` was giving me `unable to connect` error. If anyone could point out the cause, I would be thankful.